# HTTP headers with Authorize sent as OPTIONS

Tags: angularjs, http, http-headers

I am making an authentication system based on tokens. When a user logs in a token sent back and this then submitted with each call to the server

Assigning a token

```
   .factory('AuthenticationService', function($rootScope, $http, authService, $httpBackend) {
   var service = {
login: function(user) {
  $http.post('http://192.168.100.100/myApp/login', { user: user }, { ignoreAuthModule: true })
  .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = data.authorizationToken; 
    console.log("token:" + data.authorizationToken);
    authService.loginConfirmed(data, function(config) {
      config.headers.Authorization = data.authorizationToken;
      return config;
    });
  })
```

After this is executed calls are sent as `OPTIONS` rather than `POST` the problem being that I am sending to `RESTful` server and `OPTIONS` isn't ahhh ummm an option. i.e server expects `POST`, `GET` etc.

Chrome shows my headers as ..

```
General

**Remote Address:** 192.168.100.100:80
**Request URL:** http://192.168.100.100/myapp/login
**Request Method:** OPTIONS
**Status Code:** 404 Not Found

Response Headers

**Access-Control-Allow-Origin:** *
**Cache-Control:** no-cache, must-revalidate
**Connection:** Keep-Alive
**Content-Encoding:** gzip
**Content-Length:** 563
**Content-Type:** text/plain
**Date:** Tue, 04 Aug 2015 04:29:14 GMT
**Expires:** 0
**Keep-Alive:** timeout=5, max=100
**Server:** Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
**Vary:** Accept-Encoding
**X-Powered-By:** PHP/5.4.41-0+deb7u1

Request Headers

OPTIONS /myapp/login HTTP/1.1
**Host:** 192.168.100.100
**Connection:** keep-alive
**Access-Control-Request-Method:** POST
**Origin:** null
**User-Agent:** Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0; en-us; GT-I9300 Build/IMM76D)         AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
**Access-Control-Request-Headers:** authorization, content-type
**Accept:** */*
**Accept-Encoding:** gzip, deflate, sdch
**Accept-Language:** en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Will it always be `OPTIONS` and do I have to alter my `RESTful` server to accomodate this, should I not be able to see the token in the headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an preflight request to check if CORS are enaabled or not

During the preflight request, you should see the following two headers: Access-Control-Request-Method and Access-Control-Request-Headers. These request headers are asking the server for permissions to make the actual request. Your preflight response needs to acknowledge these headers in order for the actual request to work.

Shortly. You need to enable these headers at you server for actual request to work

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if CORS is enabled? if yes please try to handle OPTIONS request like this

```
if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      console.log('!OPTIONS');
      var headers = {};
      // IE8 does not allow domains to be specified, just the *
      // headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = req.headers.origin;
      headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
      headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
      headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = false;
      headers["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = '86400'; // 24 hours
      headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept";
      res.writeHead(200, headers);
      res.end();
}
```